# Scala isn’t called a “functional language” just because it’s Turing complete

Tags: functional-programming

What is the meaning of "Scala isn’t called a “functional language” just because it’s Turing complete." ? Functional languages are like others Turing comlete arent they? or lack of my english?
http://www.codecommit.com/blog/scala/scala-for-java-refugees-part-3

Comment: Once you explain a joke, it looses its humor. However, this one wasn't funny to begin with.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think the sentence structure has confused you. He isn't saying, "Just because it's Turing-complete, it isn't a functional language."

Instead, he's saying, "The term 'functional' does not mean 'Turing-complete'." In everyday English used by people who aren't programmers, when we say something is "functional," we mean "it works and is useful." Because of this, a lot of people misunderstand the term "functional" as meaning "useful" rather than "based around functions," so he's clarifying that this is not the sense in which the word is being used.

Comment: That does appear to be the issue. The guy is addressing something that probably confuses a lot of english speakers who are programming neophytes and haven't come across the term "functional programming" before. As dupdup is the opposite type of person, he read it and got confused. :-(

Comment: I actually seen a few people thinking "procedural programming" == "functional programming" because they are used to languages that use both "function" and "procedure" for subroutines (unlike e.g. Pascal, where a `procedure` doesn't return anything and a `function` is intended to be somewhat pure).